# groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild - Error with Jenkins groovy commands

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```java
def PackageLibrary(compName, projectPath){
    try{
        zipFile = "${compName}" + ".zip"
        zipCommand = "dir: " + "${projectPath}" + ", glob: '', zipFile: " + "${zipFile}"
        dir("${zipFolder}"){
            println "Zip completed************************************************* ${projectPath}"
            zip "${zipCommand}"
            println "Zip completed************************************************* ${projectPath}"
        }
    } catch(err) {
        echo "Caught: ${err}"
    } 
}
```

I am  trying to execute above command but I am getting `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` error. Logs:

```
Zip completed************************************************* ./Application_Source/TestVS10XML/obj/Debug/Package
[Pipeline] zip
Writing zip file of d:\software\jenkins\Package to d:\software\jenkins\Package\dir: .\Package, glob: '', zipFile: .TestVS10XML.zip
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] echo
Caught: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild'
```

Comment: Usually, I would say that a method that the `NodeChild` class is not serializable and you should wrap its call within a `@NonCPS`-annotated method. But in this case it more seems like a bug in the [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin) that calls this method.